# Synthetic Control Method

Tags: reference-request, applied-econometrics

I need to study Synthetic Control Method for my term paper. So can anyone suggest some book/literature from where I can study Synthetic Control Method on my own?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ressources available online

1. [Synth](https://web.stanford.edu/~jhain/synthpage.html) is a statistical software that implements synthetic control methods for causal inference in comparative case studies with aggregate data as described in Abadie and Gardeazabal (2003), Abadie, Diamond, and Hainmueller (2010), and Abadie, Diamond, and Hainmueller (2013). The Synth package for R is also described in detail in [Abadie, Diamond, and Hainmueller (2011)](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v042i13).
2. A lecture on [Synthetic Control Methods](http://yiqingxu.org/teaching/17802/synth.pdf) from [Yiqing Xu](http://yiqingxu.org/).
3. A video lecture by [Alberto Abadie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jzL0DZfr_Y) himself on  Synthetic Controls for Policy Evaluation!